# Dependency problems in Dartlang

Tags: dependencies, dart, angular

When I do a 'pub get' it gives me the following error:

Package uri has no versions that match >=0.9.3 <0.11.0 derived from:
- rpc 0.5.5 depends on version >=0.9.3 <0.11.0

```
dependencies:
  angular2: 2.0.0-beta.1
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: '^0.1.0'
  rpc: '^0.5.5'
  mongo_dart: '^0.2.4'
  http: '>=0.11.1 <0.12.0'
  crypto: '>=0.9.0 <0.10.0'
  _discoveryapis_commons: '>=0.1.0 <0.2.0'
  http_server: '^0.9.5+1'
```

uri has a version 0.10.0 and a version 0.11.0 https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uri

How can I solve this dependency clash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package name mentioned in the message is often misleading. What it actually tells is that `pub` somewhere gave up trying to find a compatible set.

Tools to debug are

- `pub get --trace`
- `pub deps -stree`
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pubviz

What's easy to forget is the SDK constraint, which may limit package versions.

At first comment out all dependencies and add one by one until you can reproduce. 
Try to figure out which combination of packages prevent resolution (usually only 2 or 3). Then investigate their SDK version and dependency constraint.

Often it's related to the analyzer package which is moving fast and often introduces breaking changes, where on dependency requires a newer version and another dependency limits to older versions.

It can of course be any other package. Maybe one that wasn't updated since a while.

Adding

```
dependency_overrides:
  uri: ^0.11.0
```

To the pubspec.yaml fixes it, therefore the `rpc` package with the `uri` constraint really seems to be the culprit.
Please create a bug report the get `rpc` made compatible with `uri` `0.11.0` or create a pull request.

Comment: I had this error with `pubviz` as well recently but didn't investigate. Can you please report? The problem could be that `rpc` doesn't allow the newest `uri` version `0.11.0`. I haven't found if a package actually required `>=0.11.0` though.

Comment: The error with `pubviz` seems to be fixed in the lated dev release.

Comment: The error with pubviz remains ("NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'isPrimary=' was called on null.") , at least when pub cannot get the dependencies (and that's exactly when I need it!).Also, pub deps reports "The pubspec.yaml file has changed since the pubspec.lock file was generated, please run "pub get" again.", which is of no help when pub get hangs indefinitely.

Comment: You get this error for `pub global activate pubviz`? The last resort kis usually to add dependencies one-by-one until it fails to find the culprit.

Comment: @Guenther: No, `activate` works well. I get the error when running `pubviz open`. Btw, I [found the culprit][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44895831/version-conflict-between-angular-components-rpc-and-sqljocky], but it doesn't help me much.

Comment: You can force a version using `dependency_overrides`

Comment: A bug report in the `pubviz` package might also be a good idea.