# Version conflict between angular_components, rpc and sqljocky

Tags: angular, dart, rpc

Is it possible to use `angular_components` together with `rpc` and `sqljocky` packages in Dart? I have a package version conflict and cannot find my way out of it.

I am using `Dart VM version: 1.23.0 (Fri Apr 21 03:13:00 2017) on "windows_x64"`
. My `pubspec.yaml` for which I can get all dependencies is

```
name: Project
description: Some description
version: 0.0.1
author: me

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.20.1 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular2: ^3.0.0
  ng_bootstrap: ">=0.5.1"
  angular_components: ">=0.5.0"
  plotly: any
  _discoveryapis_commons: ^0.1.0
  crypto: ^2.0.0
  http: ^0.11.1
  http_server: ^0.9.5+1
  logging_handlers: ^0.8.0
#  rpc: ">=0.5.0"
  csv: "^3.1.2"
#  sqljocky: '>=0.14.1'
  test: '>=0.12.20'

dev_dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1

transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

However, as soon as I reintroduce `rpc` or `sqljocky` (i.e. remove the comment sign in front of them) and run `pub get`, I get either an error

```
Package dart_style has no versions that match >=0.2.10 <2.0.0 derived from:
- angular2 3.1.0-beta depends on version >=0.1.8 <2.0.0
- code_builder 1.0.3 depends on version >=0.2.10 <2.0.0
```

(for `sqljocky`) or `pub get` hangs indefinitely with messages like

```
[...]
inconsistent constraints on quiver:
   uri 0.9.3 from hosted -> quiver >=0.17.0 <0.19.0 from hosted (quiver)
   angular2 3.1.0 from hosted -> quiver >=0.21.4 <0.26.0 from hosted (quiver)
   angular_components 0.5.1 from hosted -> quiver >=0.22.0 <0.26.0 from hosted (quiver)
 version 0.9.2 of uri doesn't match >=0.9.3 <0.12.0:
   rpc 0.5.6+3 from hosted -> uri >=0.9.3 <0.12.0 from hosted (uri)
 version 0.9.1 of uri doesn't match >=0.9.3 <0.12.0:
   rpc 0.5.6+3 from hosted -> uri >=0.9.3 <0.12.0 from hosted (uri)
[...]
```

(for `rpc`, message edited for legibility). Any suggestions?

Comment: AFAIK sqljocky's dependencies are wayyy out of date.

Comment: @Tobe O: Yes, it doesn't seem to be maintained. But what about rpc? It is written by the Dart Team and the last update is less than two months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of [package:uri](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uri) was published with a wider constraint on [package:quiver](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver), which should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem: https://output.jsbin.com/varenekizi

rpc -> uri -> `quiver <0.22.0`

You need a more recent pkg/quiver for angular_compenents.

Fix in pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
  quiver: 0.25.0
```

Comment: Can I ask how you were able to track this down? I always find it confusing to read "pub get -v" output.

Comment: It's a bit more art than science. I created a pubspec.yaml in an empty dir and added both rpc and angular_components as deps. Then commented each out in turn and looked at the graph using https://github.com/kevmoo/pubviz

Comment: Cool... I just wrote a package today to diagnose these conflicts and print them in a more user-friendly way: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_mediator

Comment: Thanks, but quiver 0.25.0 doesn't work. The rpc reports "No such method" for toLowerCase() in discoveryapis_generator/src/apis_files_generator.dart:68. However, quiver 0.22.0 works. Do you mind updating your answer?